# Autoincrement in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to know in ASP.NET MVC3, can we autoincrement primary key

In below site, there is a clear way to do this, but I could not see Identity See or Identity increment properties. Is this feature NOt available now (or) there is some other way.

http://dashingquill.web.officelive.com/blogs/create_comments_in_asp_net_mvc_website.aspx

Thanks
Suresh G

Comment: What you really want is to set an Identity column as a primary key in the comments table in your SQL Server. Then you will insert data in this database through some kind o Database Access Layer (like linq-to-sql, entity framework, nhibernate or just plain simple ADO.Net). This has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC! I suggest you read http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs to understand these things better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity is set in the database.  MVC has nothing to do with it.  When a field is set to be an Identity field, then when a new record is created, the field is automatically incremented by the database.